# Error: Invalid argument(s): –invPtrLoc

Tags: linux, oracle, installation, weblogic12c, silent-installer

I am trying to install weblogic on linux by using below command

```
java -jar ./fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar -silent -responseFile /home/user1/wls.rsp –invPtrLoc /home/user1/oraInst.loc

Invalid argument(s): –invPtrLoc,/home/user1/oraInst.loc

[user1@dev1 weblogic]$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

Please help!

Comment: Use a lowercase i! -invPtrLoc

Comment: Used that also but same output

Comment: The `–` in that option is not a normal dash/minus sign, it's some fancy character. Retype.

Comment: @Mat yes that helped. Thanks☺️